# RabbitMQ: Pika Connections reset by peer error

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

The messages I'm getting in the queue are big and the callback function takes 40-50  seconds to finish processing per message. I have the following part of code in the callback function:

```
if ch.is_open:
    print "channel is open: ", ch.is_open
    print "Method delivery tag: ", method.delivery_tag
else:
    print "Channel is closed"

ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

I will get always the print from if statement as below:

```
Channel is open: True
Method delivery tag: x #Some number
```

But i get the following error after the print statements,

```
  File "receive_vb.py", line 200, in <module>
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1822, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 758, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 521, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1445, in _dispatch_events
    evt.body)
  File "receive_vb.py", line 180, in callback
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2031, in basic_ack
    self._flush_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1292, in _flush_output
    *waiters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 477, in _flush_output
    result.reason_text)
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: (-1, "error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')")
```

For the first message itself. So i tried running without `basic_ack`, the message gets processed and hits the error randomly at different messages. 2nd message, 474th message, 181st msg and so on.

I tried setting `heartbeat_interval = 0` and some big numbers like, also `heartbeat_interval =150` Nothing worked out. How do I solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Following is the RabbitMQ log

```
=INFO REPORT==== 5-Jul-2019::03:58:56 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.17625.50> (10.168.37.108:45318 -> 10.168.37.108:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Jul-2019::03:58:56 ===
connection <0.17625.50> (10.168.37.108:45318 -> 10.168.37.108:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Jul-2019::03:59:26 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.17625.50> (10.168.37.108:45318 -> 10.168.37.108:5672):
{writer,send_failed,{error,timeout}}
```

Comment: Could you check your server settings as well (try to find anything resembling 30 seconds - your timeout after exactly 30 seconds looks suspicious).  You can't override server maximum from the client side (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721178/pika-blockingconnection-rabbitmq-connection-closed)

Comment: And I assume you are not doing anything you are not supposed to to, like using threads

Answer (score 0):

Your messages are ***too big*** to send over the network before the TCP write times out in RabbitMQ:

```
{writer,send_failed,{error,timeout}}
```

You should compress your messages to make them smaller, or split them up into multiple messages. Your network may be overloaded, or your server overloaded. Or, there may be other network or server issues preventing the fast delivery of messages - there is not enough information here to diagnose it.

As a last resort, you can increase the socket write timeout for RabbitMQ via `tcp_listen_options.send_timeout` but this would only cover up the symptom of the real root cause.